# Update for MongoCollection<Documnet>

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update the document but I am not able to do it.
I tried using update() as well as updateOne() methods..None of it worked.

```
public boolean updateDocument(String docId, String JSONString) {
     try{
         MongoCollection<Document> collection = getCollection("abc");
         DBObject queryObject = (DBObject)(collection.find(eq("_id","docId")).first()); 
         if(queryObject==null)
             return false;
         else {
             DBObject updateObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(JSONString);
             collection.update(queryObject, updateObject);
             return true;
         }
     }catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         return false;
     }
}
```

The Error is coming like this : The method update(dbObject,dbObject) is undefined for the type MongoCollection
I can use updateOne is applicable for Bson arguments but I need to use for DbObjects..
Can anyone can suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked..I needed to use MongoCollection type beacuse in the whole class I have specifed with this only.

```
 public boolean updateDocument(String docId, String JSONString) {
     try{
         MongoCollection<Document> collection = getCollection("123");
         Document queryObject = collection.find(eq("_id",docId)).first();                //finding the document then converting to DBObject type
         if(queryObject==null)
             return false;
         else {
             Document updatedoc = new Document();
             updatedoc = Document.parse(JSONString);
             collection.updateOne(queryObject,updatedoc );
             return true;
         }
     }catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         return false;
     }
}
```